# How do I represent this in terms of m and x

Tags: calculus, physics

This is the problem:

Let $t$ be the time it takes an object to fall $x$ feet. The kinetic energy of a ball of mass, $m$ dropped vertically $x$ feet is $E = {1 \over 2} m v^2$, where v = $h'$, and $h = x - 16t^2$. Find a formula for E in terms of $m$ and $x$.

So: $$h' = 1 -32t$$ $$v = h' = 1 - 32t$$ which leaves me with the equation: $$E = {1 \over 2} m * (1-32t)^2$$

Here I have $m$ as one of my inputs, but no where is there an $x$, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you just proved that $E$ is independent of $x$...

Comment: the "in terms of m and x" then i just meant as a concept check? ...which apparently I've failed :[

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId, then $v=h'=1-32t$ should actually be $v=h'=-32t$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gt6989b hinted, $x$ is constant, so its derivative is 0. The kinetic energy is actually independent of initial vertical position as it is a  function of speed alone.

Yes the speed of the object will be higher if dropped from a  greater height but this will be reflected in the range for the values of $t$ you can pick.
Of course, the falling object will have a maximum kinetic energy right before hitting the ground. So, $h^\prime = -32t$. Be sure to calculate and indicate the maximum value $t$ can take.